# Problems with Array.delete_at in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two array functions:

```
def available_billing_address_types
  options = []
  options << "Home" if address.present?
  options << "Organisation" if organisation.present?
  return options         
end

def available_billing_address_types
  options = ["Home", "Organisation"]
  options.delete_at(0) if address.blank?
  options.delete_at(1) if organisation.blank?
  return options         
end
```

The first one works as expected, the seconds one doesn't.

I suspect that it's not possible to tun `delete_at()` twice?

Or what am I missing here?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this array:

```
options = ["Home", "Organisation"]
```

If you now call `options.delete_at(0)` you have this array:

```
options = ["Organisation"]
```

So if you now call `options.delete_at(1)` there is no element `1` to delete.

You could do this:

```
def available_billing_address_types
  options = ["Home", "Organisation"]
  options.delete("Home") if address.blank?
  options.delete("Organisation") if organisation.blank?
  return options         
end
```

Comment: OK, this is a little embarrassing. Couldn't see the wood for all the trees. Thanks!!